# Sort A to Z Tables in sql

Tags: sql-server, sorting

How can I sort A to Z tables with Tables name in SQL SERVER? for example:

- dbo.customers
- dbo.zone
- dbo.jobs
- dbo.account

Sorting like:

- dbo.account
- dbo.customers
- dbo.jobs
- dbo.zone

Priority any button in menu bar or something then query for sorting.

Comment: `order by table_name` ??

Comment: thanks, i do it : SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM HR.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables 
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question

```
SELECT name  FROM sys.tables order by 1
```

Comment: its helpful,  do you know how can i do it with menu bar buttons or tabs in sql server?

Comment: Clearly I did not truly read your question.  My tables show up in order.  Looking for an option

Comment: i test it in adventureworks2012, but my boss sort his db tables in object explorer and i don't know how he did it, query for sorting is my escape way.

Comment: Looking at object explorer as well.  Would love to know how he changed the order,  Did he apply a filter?

Comment: OK, I think I got it.  Hit F7, the object explorer tab will open, then you can click on the title [Name] to toggle sort

Comment: actually idont know, i think filter on table`s is separate from the sorting!

Comment: First I had to confirm that you could NOT change the sort sequence in the tree, then I realized you were talking about the Object Explorer tab.  Cheers